# Jump to zotero from emacs failed

Tags: emacs

I'd like to jump to zotero when I click zotero links like `zotero://select/items/1_2S5A64QI` in my org file, but at the first time it doesn't work (no response). After opened the .emacs file and `M-x RET eval-buffer RET`, I backed to the org file, this time I can jump to the zotero successfully. What cause it?

```
(defun zotero-org (path)
(browse-url (format "zotero:%s" path)))
(org-add-link-type "zotero" 'zotero-org)
```

This is what I use to add a new link type.

Comment: Do you have another configuration file that's [taking precedence](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Find-Init.html), e.g. possibly an `~/.emacs.el` file? Do other things in your `~/.emacs` file work automatically, without manually evaluating the buffer?

Answer (score 2):

You need to add-link after org is loaded.

Besides, `org-add-link-type` is obsolete since 9.0; use `org-link-set-parameters` instead.

```lisp
(defun org-zotero-open (path)
  (browse-url (format "zotero:%s" path)))

(with-eval-after-load 'org
  (org-link-set-parameters "zotero" :follow #'org-zotero-open))
```

Comment: Thanks, but it seems still not work. It seems still not run after org is loaded.

Comment: Then I suspect that there is something else in your configuration that is causing the conflict, so I suggest using emacs -Q with minimal configuration to see if you can reproduce it.